# Three.js models turning black after calling computeVertexNormals?

Tags: three.js

I'm importing 3D models into three.js using MTLLoader and OBJLoader.  The .obj files contain no normals so the resulting models look blocky.  I'm attempting to smooth them by converting the BufferGeometry returned by OBJLoader into a Geometry object, and then calculating the normals.  This works perfectly for many objects, but some of them [turn almost completely black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Ueh.jpg).

Investigating this, I noticed that on the models that turn black the vertex normals (computed by computeVertexNormals()) are (0, 0, 0) for almost every vertex, while on the normal-looking models they are decimal values between -1 and 1.

Here is my code:

```
function loadModel() {

    // Load the materials first
    mtlLoader.load('texture.mtl', function (materials) {
        materials.preload();

        // Load the object and attach the materials
        objLoader
            .setMaterials(materials)
            .load('model.obj', function (object) {
                object.children[0].geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(object.children[0].geometry);
                object.children[0].geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                object.children[0].geometry.mergeVertices();
                object.children[0].geometry.computeVertexNormals();

                scene.add(object);
            }, undefined, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

How can I fix/prevent this?

Comment: On the objects where you get `[0, 0, 0]` normals, are all the faces connected? Or are they all individual triangles?

Comment: @Marquizzo I didn't make the objects, but the faces appear to all be connected (they share a lot of the vertices).

Comment: Hard to pinpoint without looking at your model, but you could try keeping it as BufferGeom and calculating only vertex normals. Instead of converting into 'Geometry'

Comment: @Marquizzo Here is the contents of the .obj file: https://pastebin.com/kPpZB9ci.  I didn't post the texture, but I don't think it's necessary since the model is black regardless of the texture.

Comment: @ihatevectors It appears your obj model is essentially two identical models -- one with front faces and one with back faces. After merging vertices, the front-facing normals and back-facing normals cancel each other out.

Comment: @WestLangley Hmm.  Since the majority of the models aren't like this, I'd need a way to detect models with this problem and fix them.  I guess checking the computed normals and looking for (0, 0, 0) would detect models with this problem, but then is there a way to fix it?  Manually adjust the normals somehow?  Or possibly delete the duplicated faces?

Comment: @ihatevectors You're on your own on that one...